# Disable click event while using other events

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

I am using Aframe 0.7.0. and it working great! My application has camera with cursor and the raycaster intersect with entities.

I want to disable click event that is emitted by intersection of cursor and any entity, but at same time I want other events to work just fine, like mouseenter, etc.
How can I achieve this? Please let me know if I am missing any information required for this question.
Thanks

Comment: can't you remove the event listeners wherever you react on clicks ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I tried `event.preventDefault()` on `click` and `fusing` events, but it is not working. may you can show me a way? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i'm correct about Your idea, You should be able to do something like this.

- Activate clicking on stuff using the `addEventListener("click", handler)`
- Deactivate clicking on stuff using the `removeEventListener("click", handler)`

Having those in Your component,

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
 addListeners: function() {
  this.el.addEventListener("click", this.handler);
 },
 removeListeners: function() {
  this.el.removeEventListener("click", this.handler);
 },
 handler: function() {
   // whatever response from clicking
 }
});
```

You can enable clicking by using `el.components.foo.addListeners` and disable using `el.components.foo.removeListeners` from any other method.

Check out my example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f9fa3oez/12/). right box enables, disables the click event on the left one. Check it out in the console.